# Do not escape special characters on form submit

Tags: php, html, forms, escaping

I have a form that submits via GET, and one of the hidden fields submits a list of category IDs, separated by comma (1,2,3).

When the get query gets to the page it is going, commas become escaped with `%2C`.

I cannot make changes to PHP that parses these values, and they must remain commas.

In summary: `?category=1,2,3` works, and `?category=1%2C2%2C3` doesn't.

How do I prevent the comma from being encoded?

Edit to address the comment, simplified, but gives you the gist:

```
<form method="get" action="something.php">
<input type="hidden" name="category" value="1,2,3">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: How are you forming the query and how is the submit done?

Comment: Can't use post, the web service only takes GET.

Comment: Poorly-written web service.  Change to onsubmit method of the form tag to create your querystring and window.open or window.location.href it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with "making it stop" is that the encoding is a part of HTTP standards - you "shouldn't want" to make it stop since it is a part of the very basis upon which HTTP is built. [RFC2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396) describes which characters are allowed and not allowed in a URI:

> 2.2. Reserved Characters
>
> Many URI include components consisting of or delimited by, certain
> special characters.  These characters are called "reserved", since
> their usage within the URI component is limited to their reserved
> purpose.  If the data for a URI component would conflict with the
> reserved purpose, then the conflicting data must be escaped before
> forming the URI.
>
> ```
>   reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
>                 "$" | ","
> ```

Because of this fact, when using GET to submit a form, the user agent will encode the values according to this specification.

Your solution lies in either

1. Change the form to use the POST method, change references to `$_GET` into `$_POST` in php
2. Call urldecode ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)) on the data before using it (`$_GET['my_value'] = urldecode($_GET['my_value']);`)
3. Use element arrays to submit this as an array to the server

On PHP side, `$_GET['myElement']` will be equal to `array(1,2,3)`

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript to manually encode the query string? A bit ugly, but it looks like it is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 hidden fields with the same name "category" and a different value 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: I tried that, and the result was: ?category=1&category=2&category=3

Answer (score 0):

Instead of preventing encoding, consider decoding the string when you receive it.  Here is an example (using java):

```
public class Encoden
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String encodedValue;
        String value = "a, b, c";
        String unencodedValue;

        try
        {
            encodedValue = URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8");
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exception)
        {
            encodedValue = null;

            System.out.print("encoding exception: ");
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }

        try
        {
            unencodedValue = URLDecoder.decode(encodedValue, "UTF-8");
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exception)
        {
            unencodedValue = null;
            System.out.print("decoding exception: ");
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.print("Original: ");
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.print("Encoded: ");
        System.out.println(encodedValue);
        System.out.print("Decoded: ");
        System.out.println(unencodedValue);
    }
}
```

I just noticed the php tag.  While I dont know php, I'm certain that it will have a means to encode and decode HTML string values.

**Edit:**
Based on comments, try rendering the value of the hidden inside a CDATA block.  I have no idea if this will work, just throwing it out there.  Here is an example:

`<input type="hidden" name="blam" value="<![CDATA[1, 2, 3]]>"/>`

Comment: Thank you, I considered that, but sadly, I cannot make modifications to the receiving side.

Comment: Can you make changes on the page rendering side?

Comment: By that point it is too late, as the model that pulls the data for the block has already ignored the list of categories being submitted.

Comment: By "rendering side" I mean rendering of the form that is submitted to the "unchanging" receiving side.