# GET method failing to receive selection php

Tags: php, forms, get

I have a form that contains 2 input texts when I submit one input text has that value contains a "John & Smith" and the second input contains "Apple" my url returns

```
www.example.com/results.php?name=John&food=Apple
```

I would like it to contain John & Smith under name because i use that for my search criteria

Comment: That is not the behaviour I would expect to see. You need to provide a complete, reduced test case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This post will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095474/do-not-escape-special-characters-on-form-submit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must URL encode your form values if you want them to be part of the query string.  See [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) for more details.  Perhaps this should be a POST request, with the params in the request body though?

Comment: upvote not only for right answer, but for linking MDN over say w3schools :)

Comment: @ficuscr MDN is indeed a great place for DOM & javascript-related reference questions.  It is informative, accurate, and, quite frankly, much easier to parse than the W3C or ECMA specification documents.

Answer (score 0):

Form data is automatically urlencoded in modern browsers.
And i did just test that in latest Chrome browser version.

If you still insist on GET method try to use this:

```
<form action="results.php" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
   <input type="text" name="name" />
   <input type="text" name="food" />
   <input type="Submit" value="Submit form data" />
</form>
```

However usually you would do only GET method with predefined values.