# Keep text from escaping / add watchers to Jira ticket

Tags: python, django, jira

So, I've hacked this together from a few sources, so if I'm totally going about it the wrong way I welcome feed back.  It also occurs to me that this is not possible, as it's probably a security check designed to prevent this behavior being used maliciously.

But anyway:

I have a form on our Django site where people can request to change the name of one of our items, which should automatically create a jira ticket.  Here's the form:

```
<form target="_blank" action='http://issues.dowjones.net/secure/CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa' method='get' id='create_jira_ticket_form'>

    <a id='close_name_change_form' class="close">&times;</a>
    <label for="new_name">New name: </label>
    <input id="new_name" type="text" name="new_name" value="{{item.name}}">
    <input type="hidden" value="10517" name="pid">
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="issuetype">
    <input type="hidden" value="5" name="priority">
    <input type="hidden" value="Change name of {{item.name}} to " name="summary" id='summary'>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{request.user}}" name="reporter">
    <input type="hidden" value="user123" name="assignee">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="description" id="description">
    <input id='name_change_submit' class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Create JIRA ticket">


</form>
```

Then I have a little JS to amend the fields with the new values:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#create_jira_ticket_form').submit(function(){

    var watchers = ' \[\~watcher1\] \[\watcher2\]';

    var new_name = $('#new_name').val();

    var summary = $('#summary').val();

    $('#summary').val(summary + new_name);

    $('#description').val(summary + new_name + watchers);

  })

})
```

It comes very close to working, but the description field is escaped, leaving it looking like:

Change name of OLDNAME to NEWNAME %5B%7Ewatcher1t%5D %5B%7Ewatcher2%5D

Which is less than helpful.  How can I keep it as is so I can add watchers?

Comment: watchers is created by django? or is this a JS question?

Comment: Watchers is a hard-coded string that would say '[~watcher1] [~watcher2]' (the values of watcher1 and 2 don't change)

Comment: You should take a look here http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: It works perfectly on my end, but when it gets submitted to Jira, it gets escaped.

Comment: When does your end stop? Right before submit?

Comment: When I submit, it opens a new window with the Jira ticket ready to be created, but the text is escaped.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your form encodes the fields and values in your form.

You can try this out by this simple snippet:

```
console.log($('form').serialize());
```

you should see something like

```
description=ejdd+%5B~watcher1%5D+%5Bwatcher2%5D
```

in order to prevent this you should change your `method='get'` to `method='post'`.

The encoding happens because it's apart of HTTP, [read here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095474/do-not-escape-special-characters-on-form-submit)
You can also read [the spec paragraph](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13)

> 17.13.3 Processing form data

Comment: That's what I'm trying to prevent, though.